# How to put seach box inside in a dropbox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have problem how to put seach box inside in a dropbox, I had already a code using some javascript but It didn't work can you please help me about it?

Here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                    $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
                    });
    </script>
```

here's my select tag codes:

```
 <?php 
                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM barangay");
                ?>
                <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="barangay_ID" style='width:160px;height:38px;border-radius:8px;border-color:#D7D7D7;margin-left:55px;' autofocus required>
                                <option disabled selected hidden>&larr; Please select &rarr;</option>
                            <?php
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                                echo "<option value='".$row['barangay_ID']."'>".$row['barangay_name']."</option>";
                            }
                            echo "</select>";
                            ?>
```

Don't know why it doesn't work please help me[an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Msb3Z.png)

Comment: Do you have jquery loaded? Are you sure? Are there errors in your console? What does your rendered HTML look like (the HTML, not a picture of it, please).  Lastly - we've found that the [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) library works great for this sort of thing.

Comment: I've got it .. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDgRdB2m4Bc

Comment: Why is that it doesn't work in chrome ???